# Apache, Issue routing a certain endpoint to a different port using Location

Tags: apache, web-hosting, httpd.conf

I'm trying to route any links that start with /api/ to port 3002 on my server but they always get routed to 3008. For example https://example.com/api/customers should be proxied/routed to localhost:3002

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin (redacted)
    ServerName (redacted)
    ServerAlias (redacted)

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/(redacted)/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/(redacted)/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/(redacted)/chain.pem

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Location "/api\/(.*)/">
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3002/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3002/
    </Location>

    <Location "/">
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3008/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3008/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Using this config going to domain.com works and shows my website but domain.com/api/customers returns an error from the webapp on port 3008 so it's not being routed correctly (it should go to 3002).

The apps on port 3008 and 3002 are running correctly so that's not the issue.
I've tried putting domain/ first and domain/api last in the config file but that didnt seem to fix it. And the config file is enabled

I've tried different regexes to match the api endpoint aswell but this one should work

Apache is listening on port 443

These mods are enabled which should be needed for this:
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)

Please let me know if you want any extra information

Answer (score 0):

Modify your config as below and have a try.

Post the access log and curl response if not working.

curl -ILKv https://domain.name/api/anything

curl -ILKv https://domain.name/api

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /api http://localhost:3002
ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:3002
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it like this:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule "/api\/(.*)" "http://localhost:3002/api/$1" [P] 

<Location "/">
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3008/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3008/
</Location>
```